# How can I implement animation in my flatlist?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-flatlist

I am using Flatlist in my rn project and when I push new data into my flatlist, my item 1 will automatically move from position A to position B. But my question is I don't want it to just change the position, I want to use animation to move my item(from position A to position B). How can I implement that? Thank you!

Please check the demo picture and video from the link down below:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/WypswNyA38A2EAPQA
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Ev1RYMduDj7mxrHn7

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Animated` component to do the animation. As per your attached video, 2 steps animation comes into play, one which pushes the items up in the list and another one which increases the opacity of the list item. A simple approach would be to add the list item with height `0` and increase the height to desired height using animation, this will complete the first step. Once the first step is completed, control the `opacity` to go from `0` to `1`.

Next, you need to start the animation when the list item is added to the list, `componentDidMount` is the right place to do so. Please consider the following component which does the above steps.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

class AnimatedListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
    this.state = {
      height: new Animated.Value(0),
      opacity: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.height,
        {
          toValue: this.props.height,
          duration: this.props.duration || 1000
        }
      ),
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.opacity,
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: this.props.duration || 1000
        }
      )
    ]).start();
  }

  render() {
    const { height, opacity } = this.state;
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          ...this.props.style,
          height: height,
          opacity: opacity
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

export default AnimatedListItem;
```

In the above snippet, two animations are passed to `Animated.sequence([...])` method to animate one after the other.

You can now use the above component in the `renderItem` method like

```
renderItem = () => {
  return (
    <AnimatedListItem height={50} duration={800} style={...}>
      /* render actual component here */
    </AnimatedListItem>
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!

**Note**: This is a bare minimum example to achieve what you are looking for.